# TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of null

Tags: node.js

TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of null

This is my code snippet.Please tell me what is the issue?What I am doing wrong
here I am checking the admin password and id

```
    router.post('/login', function (req, res, next) {
console.log('Entered post /login');
req.app.db.models.Admin.findOne({
    'login_id': req.body.login_id
}, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return next(err);
    }
    if (data.password == req.body.password) {
        var payload = {
            userType: 'admin',
            firstName: 'Admin'
        };
        var token = req.app.jwt.sign(payload, req.app.jwtSecret);
        // add token to cookie
        res.cookie('token', token);
        res.redirect('/admin');
    } else {
        res.redirect('/admin/login');
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Hey, just check with your data variable in your code. It is not a valid object . console.log(data). If it is object then check whether it contains password key.

Comment: It seems that you `res.body` object is `undefined`. Have you setup https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser correctly? Have you sent body correctly from frontend client?